# How does ジャンケンポン become the meaning for the rock paper and scissors game?

Tags: meaning, words, etymology

It's the term used for the rock, paper and scissors game. I have also heard the term kai bai bo/bou used. Which term is correct? Kai bai bo/bou sounds Chinese. How does jyankenpon and kai bai bo/bou relate to iwa, kami, and hasami?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6391/9831

Comment: @Chocolate, my question has been answered. I guess the kai bai bou part is Chinese.